# Trim string in JSF

Tags: jsf

I am building a Web application using JSF.
I have the following line in my code:

where the value is being fetched from properties file.
Suppose if the value of that particular key changes in the properties file,I don't want this value to be displayed with increased length.
Rather I need to display original string and append it with "..."
How can I achieve this?

Comment: <h:outputLabel for="search" value="#{Res['search']}:" />

Comment: This is the line used in my code

Comment: please provide an example about how it's working now how do you want it to work

Comment: you can do something like `value = #{ Res['search'] == 'myKeyWord' ? 'show what i want ' : '...' }` this is mean if my `Res['search']`  found the key word that i am searching for it will show what i want else it will show  '...'

Comment: Presently if the value of key search is "SEARCH" (in the properties file), it displays as SEARCH itself.But I need to limit the length of string to two and  I want it to display as SE...

Comment: you will need to make a String method to make it return a String

Comment: You can edit your question and add relevant code there...

Comment: learn about css ellipsis

Comment: How does change imply increased length?